# TypeScript - function ON an element

Tags: javascript, typescript

Ok, this is a little bit hard to explain for me. I want to be able to do things like this in TypeScript:

```
(function() {
    (function($) {
        ...
    })(jQuery);
});
```

I know that when I create a TypeScript "MyClass" with a constructor "constructor ($) {...}" and export this class it gets compiled to nearly the same, but how can I create the "(jQuery)" parameter? What I like to do is call myFunction on a jQuery element:

```
$("#myDiv").MyClass.myFunction();
```

so I have the element in my class and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could *force* a class as a jquery extension but I don't recommend it. This is because JQuery extensions rely on `this` being the current JQuery object which is the target of the current extension function call.

I recommend you use a simple function. And use a class inside that function if you need to. Here is a basic jquery extension in typescript:

```
// from jquery.d.ts
interface JQuery{}
declare var $:{(str:string):JQuery;fn:any;};

// Your code: 

// Basic jquery extension in TypeScript
interface JQuery{
    myFunction();
}
$.fn.myFunction = function(){
    console.log(this);
}

$("#myDiv").myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is primarily a separation of concerns issue. Your class should contain the functionality of your jQuery plugin, while a function should provide access to that functionality.

```
module MyExtension {

    var $ = jQuery;

    export class MyClass {

        constructor (public $target: JQuery) {}

        public doSomething () {

            console.log('MyClass did something to', this.$target);
        }
    }

    export function jqueryPlugin () {

        return new MyClass(this).doSomething();
    }
}

if (jQuery) jQuery.fn.extend({ myExtension: MyExtension.jqueryPlugin });
```

Comment: thanks for the answers; this is very inspiring and enlightening